# I want to display the value in the ComboBox in the index file

Tags: laravel-5

I want to display the value of the ComboBox in the index file ... but I get an error ...
this is on my controller :

```
$kategori = Kategori::lists('nama','nama');
 return view('barangs.index', compact('kategori'));
```

and this is in my index file :

```
  <select name="model" id="model" class="form-control" required>
               <option value="">Select Model</option>
          @foreach($kategori as $Model)
               <option value="{{ $Model->nama }}">{{ $Model->nama }}</option>
          @endforeach
 </select>
```

this error :

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: kategori (View: D:\NOVA\GIT\UmajeePOS v.2\resources\views\barangs\index.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Undefined variable: kategori (0)
```

Comment: Hi. please use ```dd($kategori)``` in your index view and tell what do you see?

Comment: still error @MohammadHosseini

Comment: So this means $kategori not passed to view...second step return $kategori after you get in first line in your controller and tell result